# JavaScript Object not recognizing property

Tags: javascript, oop, object, properties

I'm having an odd error with a JS object, it goes like this:

```
function MatchManager(){
    this.current_m = [];
}

MatchManager.prototype.addMatchBatch = function (array){
    // yes I could do an apply..
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        this.current_m.push(array[i]);
    }
}
```

However, when I call `addMatchBatch` on an instance of `MatchManager` I get `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined`. Which means that current_m is not being recognized by the Instance.

I also tried adding `var parent=this;` and changing `this` by `parent` inside the `for` loop, to no avail.

I'm guessing `this` references the addMatchBatch function instead of the Instance... how do I overcome this?

If anyone has any idea why, I will be very grateful!

Thanks a lot!

PS: I'm calling and instantiating my objects like so:

```
MatchManager.prototype.getCurrent = function(){
    var options : {
        url : myUrl,
        method: "GET",
        callback: this.addMatchBatch
    };

    AJAXCall(options);
}

var manager = new MatchManager();
manager.getCurrent();
```

Comment: Please show how exactly are you calling the function.

Comment: … including how you create the instance.

Comment: The function is being called from a callback on a XMLHttpRequest from another method of MatchManager, and the instanciation is simply `var manager = new MatchManager()`

Comment: Don't vaguely describe how you are calling it. Provide a proper [test case](http://sscce.org/) so we can reproduce the problem. (I ran that code, made assumptions about how you were using it, and the problem you described did not occur).

Comment: @Quentin added to the question ;)

Comment: There's still no `.addMatchBatch` call in the post ... Notice, that setting `callback: this.addMatchBatch` assigns just a reference to `callback`, not context. You've to bind the context when you're actually calling the method.

Comment: its the callback on AJAXCall, it is called when the response arrives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> callback: this.addMatchBatch
> ```

You are passing the function as an argument, but the value of `this` inside it depends on the context in which it is *called* and whatever `AJAXCall` does, it isn't calling it in the first context.

Create a new function which calls it in the right context and pass that function instead.

```
callback: this.addMatchBatch.bind(this)
```

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick ;)